# HTML + CSS Rendered colors

Tags: html, css, colors, styles

I don't know why I'm getting two different colors when the page loads. I look into Computed and Styles tabs from the element inspector, but this shows me the same values for each one.

Image:
[image]
[image]
[image]

The first style is for the title, and the other for the "Seguir Leyendo", a "Read more" link, both on top of all, without alphas and nothing to give different tones.

Any clue why this could happend?

Add:

HTML:

```
<div class="blog_entry">
    <div class="blog_entry_image">
        <a href="home-blog-detail-one.html"><img src="img/blog_imagen_1.png" class="blog_image_home"alt="Blog entry 1"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_entry_desc">
    <h2 class="blog_entry_title"><a href="home-blog-detail-one.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                        adipiscing lit. Phaiop ellus ut diam nibh consectetur adpiscing</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_entry_date">
        28 Diciembre 2014
    </div>
    <div class="blog_entry_text">
        <p>Nulla arcu quam, tempor a mattis sit amet, efficitur eget ante. Integer elit 
                        libero, rutrum eu augue ut, faucibus dictum nibh. Suspendisse vitae ex sit amet 
                        tellus molestie interdum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_entry_options">
        <img src="img/blog_facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
        <img src="img/blog_twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
        <a href="home-blog-detail-one.html">Seguir leyendo  <img src="img/arrow_read_more.png" alt="Seguir leyendo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blog_entry_title {
    font-size: 24px;
}
.blog_entry_title a, .blog_title_detail {
    color: #008ed6;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: HelveticaNeueThin;
}
.blog_entry_options {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.blog_entry_options a {
    color: #008ed6;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Comment: Without the HTML code, I can not totally be sure. But I assume that one is a header and has additional CSS properties.

Comment: please paste some html .. only diff i get here is font-size.. just try yourself by making both the font-size same and paste the result..

Comment: It has to be some additional styles. Maybe read more is a link, and Lorem ipsum is a h1, h2.. element ???

Check in firebug for any additional styles. It should helps.

Comment: @Michat Kutra both's are links, title is a link inside an h2. I looked with element inspector, both tabs, Styles and Computed, and I cannot see many differences, both haves the same rgb color (not rgba), not alphas or opactity...

Comment: there is no color difference are there, the only thing is the font-weight, try to update font-weight and font-size, you wont see any color difference!!

Comment: @Aru definetly was that, need a font-weight normal, only that made the color turn very different, even making a screenshot and picking the color in photoshop told me was the same. Thanks! Add the answer and ill check it as good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By updating/resetting the `font-weight` you can see the magic :

*CSS :*

```
.blog_entry_title a{ font-weight: normal }
```

Comment: Thought was something like that. We've got a h1 title too that has the same color that the link before, so I saw it has that font-weight normal too, just needed the h2 have it too. Thanks